Matrix Product involving Vandermonde Matrices
Suppose I'm given $\bar{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (l+1)}$ with rank $n$ such that $n<l$, i.e. $\bar{T}$ has full row rank. Additionally, I have another matrix $V$ of the form
\begin{align}
V = \begin{bmatrix}
        (jw_1)^{l}   & (jw_2)^{l}   & \ldots & (jw_{n})^{l}\\
        (jw_1)^{l-1} & (jw_2)^{l-1} & \ldots & (jw_{n})^{l-1}\\
        \vdots       & \vdots       &        & \vdots\\
        1            & 1            &        & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $w_1 \neq w_2\neq \ldots \neq w_n$ and $j = \sqrt{-1}$. If $\bar{T}$ is full rank, then is the matrix product $Q = \bar{T}V$ also full rank? I tried using Sylvester equations to go about this but it did not work out. Is there a property of Vandermonde matrices I'm missing?
Any help would be appreciated!

You haven't defined $j$.

The notation $w_1\ne w_2\ne \cdots \ne w_n$ is ambiguous. Do you mean $w_i\ne w_k$ for all $i\ne k$?

Try $T=\pmatrix{j&1}$ and $V=\pmatrix{j\1}$.

The answer seems to be no. Take   $T=\pmatrix{j&1}$ and $V=\pmatrix{j\\1}$. This is the case $n=l=1$ with $ w_1=1$.
As pointed out in a comment $T$ should be real. So another counterexample is $T=\pmatrix{1&1}$ and $V=\pmatrix{j\cdot j\\1}$ with $w_1=j$ which is admissible since it is not required that $w_1$ is real.
And finally a counterexample with also $w_1$ real:
Take $T=\pmatrix{1&1&1&1}$ and $w_1=1$.  Then $V=\pmatrix{j^3\\j^2\\j\\1}=\pmatrix{-j\\-1\\j\\1}$ and $T\cdot V=(-j+(-1)+j+1)=(0)$.
